# How do I decipher this Tensorflow error message?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Unfortunately, I can't post the code that produced this, but I'm having trouble deciphering the following error message (TensorFlow / Keras):

```
2020-09-09 11:20:35.700555: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1753] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops_fused_impl.h:716 : Invalid argument: input must be 4-dimensional[32,512,1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/train.py", line 1443, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/xxx/train.py", line 1435, in main
    args.batch_size,
  File "/xxx/train.py", line 1303, in train_main
    xxx.train(training_delta=training_delta)
  File "/home/xxx/train.py", line 591, in train
    validation_steps=len(self.val_dg),
  File "/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py", line 785, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py", line 685, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 297, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(actual_inputs)
  File "/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3632, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1472, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: tensor_in_shape must have 2 spatial dimensions. 5 0
         [[{{node average_pooling1d_7_1/AvgPool}}]]
```

I understand that `tensor_in_shape must have 2 spatial dimensions` means that the layer is expecting 2 spatial dimensions, but it's getting only 1. However, on the last line it also prints `average_pooling1d_7_1`, which should only take 1 spatial dimension. Several questions:

1. How is that related to the error message, if at all?
2. If `average_pooling1d_7_1` is not related to the error message, how do I find the layer that's causing the error?
3. What is the `5 0` printed at the end of the second to last line?

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Do you think it's look like this one https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/refs/heads/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/pooling_ops_common.cc#129 ?

Comment: Looks pretty similar. I wonder if it's trying to pool across the channel dimension here, which is size 3?

Comment: You need to post the code that produced this error. Otherwise asking for an answer is like asking for the lotto numbers.

Comment: I was asking about how to read the error message. As I mentioned, I cannot post the code for various reasons. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to diminish the size of your input from 5D to 4D